# Laravel-echo-server, net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in laravel echo redis server

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm using laravel-echo with redis for broadcast notification. It works perfectly on my local system. But on my server, I'm getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. I have no any knowledge about socket and redis. I followed instruction of laravel document and laravel echo server. But still same error.

`http://demoip.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

**js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
 
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port
});
```

If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: try to check if all ports you need is opened on your firewall, try to scan your server IP with nmap to be shure that the port is opened

Comment: @pavelbere - It's working now. Thank you. I have checked using `nmap demoip` port 6001 was not enabled. I have enabled it and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Because on server you need to allow the port for socket io echo server.

For allow port you can run this command on server `sudo ufw allow PORT_NUMBER`

If all are working fine then you need to check your node server by command on server to check server is running or any error exists `pm2 monit`

And you need to change in your js file with this code

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

I think you miss `window.io = require('socket.io-client');`